# Apache Zeppelin - Disconnected status

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have successfully installed and started Zeppelin on ec2 cluster with spark 1.3 and hadoop 2.4.1 on yarn.(as given in https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin)

However, I see zeppelin started with 'disconnected' status (on the right corner).
As per log, I find that both the zeppelin port and the websocket port (zeppeling port + 1) have been started with no error. Also, both the ports are not used by any other process and I see 
zeppelin process (pid) running on both the ports. The IP table is blank.

**log:**

```
 INFO [2015-06-30 03:20:31,294] ({main} QuartzScheduler.java[initialize]:305) - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.2.1) 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

 INFO [2015-06-30 03:20:31,294] ({main} StdSchedulerFactory.java[instantiate]:1339) - Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
 INFO [2015-06-30 03:20:31,294] ({main} StdSchedulerFactory.java[instantiate]:1343) - Quartz scheduler version: 2.2.1
 INFO [2015-06-30 03:20:31,295] ({main} QuartzScheduler.java[start]:575) - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
 INFO [2015-06-30 03:20:31,510] ({main} ServerImpl.java[initDestination]:94) - Setting the server's publish address to be /
 INFO [2015-06-30 03:20:31,625] ({main} StandardDescriptorProcessor.java[visitServlet]:284) - NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
 INFO [2015-06-30 03:20:32,374] ({main} AbstractConnector.java[doStart]:338) - Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8083
 INFO [2015-06-30 03:20:32,374] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[main]:108) - Started

 INFO [2015-06-30 03:20:30,181] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java[create]:98) - Load configuration from file:/home/ec2-user/incubator-zeppelin/conf/zeppelin-site.xml
 INFO [2015-06-30 03:20:30,336] ({main} NotebookServer.java[creatingwebSocketServerLog]:65) - Create zeppelin websocket on 0.0.0.0:8084
 INFO [2015-06-30 03:20:30,537] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[main]:106) - Start zeppelin server
 INFO [2015-06-30 03:20:30,539] ({main} Server.java[doStart]:272) - jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
```

**zeppelin-env.sh:**

```
export ZEPPELIN_PORT=8083
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/mnt/disk1/hadoop-2.4.1/etc/hadoop
export SPARK_HOME=/mnt/disk2/spark
```

In **zeppelin-site.xml**, I have only set server ip address and port and -1 for websocket port.

When I access websocket port thru chorme I get "no data received..err_empty_reponse" and "Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data' error.

Am I missing anything during installation or in configuration? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It just turns out that installation was done correctly, but the browser used was not. Zeppelin works with firefox, not with IE or Chrome.

Comment: I am facing major-minor version issue, while starting shell. The issue is being logged into the "logs" folder.. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have some experiences using apache zeppelin with IE or Chrome. Just add the  your IP address into trusted sites with internet option. Close the IE or Chrome and restart it. And then opening IE or Chrome browser, you can see main page of apache zeppelin.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the property `zeppelin.server.allowed.origins` to `*`in the `conf/zeppelin-site.xml`and check if it's a websocket issue. After you can list the origins that you would like to allow.